# Django is not serving media files in debug environment

Tags: python, django

I've looked at many other stack overflow posts and I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working

I've followed other posts and come up with this:

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'

# myapp/models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/', blank=True, null=True)

# myapp/urls.py
if (settings.DEBUG):
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am getting a 404 response from django, not sure if there is something I'm missing or not.

Running Python 3.6.1 and Django 1.10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your MEDIA_URL and your MEDIA_ROOT to

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

because MEDIA_ROOT is the absolute path where your file gonna be saved. And MEDIA_URL is the url that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT.